# Firebase Invalid Email Error in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am always getting an error while trying to register a user to firebase in my android app.

> "The email specified is invalid"

I noticed this happens on JellyBean devices and I don't know what the problem is, whether it is from the API or something else.

My code snippet is given below:

```
private void registerUser() {
        // Sign Up
            mRef.createUser(mAccount.name, mPassword, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    loginUser(true);
                }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                // Sign Up failed
                if (firebaseError.getCode() == FirebaseError.NETWORK_ERROR) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.connection_error_message)
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton("Try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    checkUserExistence();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(firebaseError.getMessage())
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton("Try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    registerUser();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this happening on other versions of Android besides Jelly Bean?

Comment: Can you provide a smaller code snippet that reproduces the problem with a hardcoded value for `mAccount.name`?

Comment: no, it works fine on lollipop and mashmallow devices.